# Golang - Execute command

Tags: go

Prompt as in golang to execute such command:

```
/bin/bash script.sh < text.txt
```

I execute a script with parameters so:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    argstr := []string{"script.sh", "arg1", "arg2"}
    out, err := exec.Command("/bin/bash", argstr...).Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

And here is how to transfer an output from the text file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you should execute is:

```
/bin/bash -c 'script.sh < text.txt'
```

So

```
argstr := []string{"-c", "script.sh < text.txt"}
```

Bash will interpret input redirection and will do the job.

Comment: Thanks! It works!
Also I found one more method:
 func main() {
  cmd := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "script.sh")
  cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader("text of the test.txt file")
  var out bytes.Buffer
  cmd.Stdout = &out
  err := cmd.Run()
  if err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
   os.Exit(1)
  }
  fmt.Println(out.String())
 }

Comment: @Konstantin You can add the other method as a new answer. I would just use `os.Open` to read the file.

Comment: Hello! Yes, it is already possible!
Thank you for the help!

Whether interestingly, perhaps to make similar not only through execution of bash-commands (a package of **"os/exec"**), and through implementation of the client of ssh (for example, means of a package of **"crypto/ssh"**)?

Answer (score 0):

**Pro Tip: Don't forget to timeout**

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 4*time.Second)
defer cancel()
argstr := []string{"/bin/bash", "-c", "script.sh < text.txt"}
cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, argstr...)
cmd.Stderr = &errorBuffer
cmd.Stdout = &outputBuffer
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("something bad happened: %v", err)
}
```

I always suggest to play safe.

Comment: Is it for some other question?

Comment: Yeah, thinking better. The title and the question were somewhat confusing. :\
Looks like the problem it's pretty much about how to handle parameters with `exec.Command()` and `bash`.